# How to log from within PHPUnit test case?

Tags: php, logging, phpunit

What is best practice for printing log statements from a PHPUnit test case?

I am running selenium test cases and want to print out something like "Log in acccomplished", "Page XY opened".

I want to see those in *any* log file I want. Would be good, if you can define a log level.

Comment: Could You expand [Your question] on what kind of log statements You want, and where You want them to be printed?

Comment: I provided some more basic information. Is the question clear now?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would suggest that You use the [Selenium Server Logging](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/05_selenium_rc.html#selenium-server-logging). It will provide You with all debugging information You might need.

If it's not an option for You and You still want to log from the `PHPUnit` test cases, You have 3 options:

1. Use the built-in logging functionality ([documentation](http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/phpunit-book.html#logging)), which can be configured through either `phpunit.xml` file or the command line arguments ([documentation](http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/phpunit-book.html#textui.clioptions));
2. Create Your own logger by implementing the `PHPUnit_Framework_TestListener` interface, which is kind of limited because it supports only a limited amount of events You can log, such as `startTest`, `endTest`, `addError`, `addFailure`, etc. See the ([documentation](http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/phpunit-book.html#extending-phpunit.PHPUnit_Framework_TestListener)) for the complete list of the supported events. You could possibly add some more events to your implementation but that would also require that You override the `PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite::run()` method by subclassing the `PHPUnit_Extensions_TestDecorator` class ([documentation](http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/phpunit-book.html#extending-phpunit.PHPUnit_Extensions_TestDecorator)) or by implementing the `PHPUnit_Framework_Test` interface ([documentation](http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/phpunit-book.html#extending-phpunit.PHPUnit_Framework_Test)).
3. The easiest and more flexible option is to subclass the `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase` class and implement the logging functionality there. This will allow You to log from within Your test methods.([documentation](http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/phpunit-book.html#extending-phpunit.PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase))

Comment: So basically there is no best practice? I am currently going like (3) but this approach is quite embarrassing to me.

Comment: It depends on what Your definition of best practice is. Regarding this case, from the PHPUnit perspective Option #2 is the preferred way of extending it through event listeners. Unfortunately, there's no easy way to register events to the code inside methods and PHPUnit (PHP) doesn't provide convenient means, so in order to add logging from inside our methods we've got only one choice: to explicitly call our logging mechanism defined in the parent class using the class inheritance (Option #3). Maybe it's not the "best" practice, but it's definitely a common one in the OOP world.

Answer (score 4):

You can implement a test listener, specify it in your `phpunit.xml.dist`,  and do whatever you want, with whatever logging system you want (Monolog is popular) See [the documentation](http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/phpunit-book.html#extending-phpunit.PHPUnit_Framework_TestListener) for a better writeup and example than I can write off the top of my head.

If you want to specify messages in the test methods, you could have your tests inherit from a common class that adds a log method. And do whatever you want in there. I don't like that as a solution, but it's certainly an option.

Comment: Thank you, however I am aware, that it is possible, because everything is possible :-) I would like to have a snippet for the first version: monolog configuration in the `phpunit.xml.dist`.

Comment: If you would like that, take the small amount of time necessary to read the introductory documentation for Monolog, and apply the code in there to what the PHPUnit docs describe -- I'm hesitant to provide a cut-and-paste answer for you when what I would be writing would practically be a cut-and-paste from the official documentation links I already provided.